# About little-o notation

Tags: notation

What is $x_{n}$ in the following equation:
$n^4$(1+o(1))+$x_{n}$=$n^4$(1+o(1))

It is o($n^4$), but I don't understand, why? Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: Deliberate duplicate? Not nice, not nice at all...

Comment: Sorry, I was desprate because I didn't understand it and did not know, what to do. I'm new in this community and did not know, that this is a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. Expand both sides:

- $n^4(1+o(1))=n^4+n^4o(1)=n^4+o(n^4)$
- so the equality can be rewritten as 
  $$n^4+o(n^4)+x_n=n^4+o(n^4)\iff x_n=o(n^4)-o(n^4)=o(n^4).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to admit, that I was stupid.. I have learned this at the end of my first semester....